# Saving and retrieving information from wordpress database

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a wordpress page on the admin area where the user can set his twitter, facebook,..., addresses. It is my first time trying something like this and I am finding it quite complicated.

Searching the net, reading here and there, I have put this code together on my function.php:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <h2>BUNT THEME SETTINGS</h2>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h3>1. Social Media Icons</h3>
    <p>Here you can set the addresses for your Social Media pages. The buttons will automatically show up on your blog.</p>

    <form method="post" action="options.php">
        <?php wp_nonce_field("update-option") ?>
        <p><strong>1.1 TWITTER:</strong>
            <input type="text" name="twitterid" size="70" value="<?php echo get_option('twitterid'); ?>" />
        </p>
        <p><input class="button button-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Save changes" /></p>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
        <input type="hidden" name="page_options" value="twitterid" />
    </form>
</wrap> <!-- end .wrap -->
```

This creates a submenu on the Settings Menu with a field to insert a twitter address and a "Save Changes" button

When I type an address and click "Save Changes" I get sent back to the options.php showing:

"Are you sure you want to do this?

Please try again."

("Please try again" is a link that will take us back to my new settings page, with the field again empty).

My goal would be that the user inputs the twitter address, which would then later be added to the twitter button on the blog. So I thought the way to to this would be to store the adress and then retrieve it for the button. Is this the way to do it?

Why isn't this working? How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better looking into the Options Framework. It makes this whole process a lot simpler.

https://github.com/syamilmj/Options-Framework